# How to filter Date (Year) in shiny based on sliderInput choice?

Tags: r, highcharts, filter, shiny, filtering

I am working with shiny and have a sliderInput() and selectInput() inside my ui.R file. I would like that based on the user choice of these both fields, to plot the selected data within hchart function. I am very close to solve the problem, but with my code, its just filtering the first number and the last number of the year and not everything between. I tried with the between function but it didnt work.

This is my ui.R code:

```
  tabItem(tabName = "crimetypesbyyear",

          fluidRow(

            box(
              title = "Date", 
              status = "primary", 
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 6,
              sliderInput("ctypeDate", label = "Select Year", min = 2001, max = 2016, step = 1, sep = '', value = c(2001,2016))
            ),

            box(
              title = "Crime Type", 
              status = "primary", 
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 6,
              height = 162,
              selectInput("ctypeCrimeType", label= "Select Crime Type", choices = unique(cc$Primary.Type)) 
            ),

            box(
              title = "Plot", 
              status = "danger", 
              solidHeader = TRUE,
              width = 12,
              highchartOutput(outputId = "ctypeOutput")
            ),
```

And this is my server.R code:

```
output$ctypeOutput <- renderHighchart({

ctypeAnalysis <- cc[cc$Primary.Type == input$ctypeCrimeType,] %>% group_by(Year2) %>% summarise(Total = n()) %>% filter(Year2 %in% cbind(input$ctypeDate[1],input$ctypeDate[2]))

hchart(ctypeAnalysis %>% na.omit(), "column", hcaes(x = Year2, y = Total, color = Total)) %>%
hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE, filename = paste(input$ctypeCrimeType, "by_Year", sep = "_")) %>%
hc_title(text = paste("Crime Type by Year",input$ctypeCrimeType, sep = ": ")) %>%
hc_subtitle(text = "(2001 - 2016)") %>%
hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Year")) %>%
hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Crimes")) %>%
hc_colorAxis(stops = color_stops(n = 10, colors = c("#d98880", "#85c1e9", "#82e0aa"))) %>%
hc_add_theme(hc_theme_smpl()) %>%
hc_legend(enabled = FALSE)
})
```

So this line of code should be corrected: `ctypeAnalysis <- cc[cc$Primary.Type == input$ctypeCrimeType,] %>% group_by(Year2) %>% summarise(Total = n()) %>% filter(Year2 %in% cbind(input$ctypeDate[1],input$ctypeDate[2]))`, somebody any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Year 2` is formatted as a factor, you need to convert it back to numeric values. You can do this in the same step as the filtering function, like so:

```
... filter(as.numeric(levels(Year2))[Year2] >= input$ctypeDate[1] & as.numeric(levels(Year2))[Year2] <= input$ctypeDate[2])
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to write that I already tried that, but geting this error: Warnung: Error in [[<-.data.frame: replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Comment: If you can provide some sample data (using dput()), I or someone else could trouble shoot it a bit more. But without that it's hard to know why you're not getting data through your filters.

Comment: the output is to big, bro.. the Year2 column just represent the year when the crime happened in 4 digit format (2001...). class = factor

Comment: @S002, ah...Knowing that `Year2` is actually formatted as a factor is helpful information. See my edited answer above

Comment: phalteman, you are genius bro <3 its working perfect brooo thanks so much :)))))

Comment: Glad it worked. Don’t forget to mark the answer as correct so that others know the solution worked for your problem.